# What is the difference between namedtuple return and its typename argument?

Tags: python

Python documentation says:

```
collections.namedtuple(typename, field_names[, verbose=False][, rename=False])
Returns a new tuple subclass named typename.
```

and it gives an example

`>>>Point = namedtuple('Point',`...

In all the examples I could find, the return from `namedtuple` and argument `typename` are spelled the same.

Experimenting, it seems the argument does not matter:

```
>>>Class = collections.namedtuple('Junk', 'field')
>>>obj = Class(field=1)
>>>print obj.field
1
```

What is the distinction? How does the `typename` argument matter?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you execute the following code:

```
Bar = collections.namedtuple('Foo', 'field')
```

you are:

1. creating a new type named `Foo`;
2. assigning that type to a variable named `Bar`.

That code is equivalent to this:

```
class Foo:
    ...

Bar = Foo
del Foo
```

Even if you assign your class to a variable with a different name, `Foo` will still be the "official" name, that is: `Bar.__name__` will still be `'Foo'`.

You'll see the difference when you print either the class or the instance:

```
>>> Bar = collections.namedtuple('Foo', 'field')
>>> obj = Bar(field=1)
>>> obj
Foo(field=1)
```

You may ask why `namedtuple` requires the type name, as it is redundant (with the usual convention). Well, `namedtuple` builds the type *before* the variable is assigned, so it cannot infer the type name and it needs to be told explicitly. (Or better: it could infer the name by inspecting the code of the caller, but that's hackish and won't work for non conventional cases.)

Comment: forgive me, but that's what I don't understand.  Why two things?  Why do we need both the official name and the variable with a possibly different name?